# Python 3 архивирование

Tags: python, zip

День добрый. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?  Запускаю на десятой винде этот код. Предварительно устанавливал GnuWin32.

```
import os
import time
source = ['C:\\Users\Public\Downloads', 'C:\\Users\Sved\Videos']
target_dir = 'D:\\Backup'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%d%m%Y%H%M%S') + '.zip'
zip_command = "zip {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
   print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
   print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Окно вывода, даёт такой результат:

```
zip D:\Backup\01062018110802.zip C:\Users\Public\Downloads 
C:\Users\Sved\Videos
zip warning: name not matched: Files
zip warning: name not matched: (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
zip warning: name not matched: D:\Backup\01062018110802.zip
updating: Users/Public/Downloads/ (196 bytes security) (stored 0%)
updating: Users/Sved/Videos/ (164 bytes security) (stored 0%)
Резервная копия успешно создана в D:\Backup\01062018110802.zip
```

Понимаю, что вопрос наверняка избитый, пытался поискать в гугле, и понял что совсем не умею им пользоваться.(

Comment: А в чем вопрос? В этих предупреждениях? А откуда в логе тот путь берется "Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin"? Кст, в питоне есть возможность zip архивы создавать, почему не через него не сделать? Вот пример рекурсивного добавления папок в архив: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/797e43a6d458240483a18abb16c9348bb47feef2/zip_file_example/append_directory/main.py

Comment: Суть в том что, архивирование само не происходит, но спасибо за ссылку сделаю как полагается.

Comment: Если архивирования нет, тогда этот вопрос больше к GnuWin32. Попробуйте вызвать просто через cmd

Comment: У вас путь к GnuWin32 разбился по пробелам. Скорее всего там где он прописан нужно обернуть путь в кавычки.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа запустила **не** прямо `zip.exe`, а `zip.bat`, который затем хотел запустить самой `zip.exe`, содержа приблизительно такую команду:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.exe .....
```

Для вас теперь 3 пути, как это исправить:

1. В файле `zip.bat` добавите кавычки:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\zip.exe" ...
   ```
2. Переименуйте файл `zip.bat` - например на `zip_orig.bat`, надеясь что путь к `zip.exe` операционная система знает (т.е. он в `PATH`).
3. В команде

   ```
   zip_command = "zip {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
   ```

   добавите `.exe` (или даже полный путь к `zip.exe`):

   ```
   zip_command = "zip.exe {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Есть подозрение, что GnuWin32 вы установили по умолчанию в папку C:\Program Files (x86), а в примере, который вы взяли из книги "A Byte of Python" написано, что добавить в переменную окружения PATH нужно C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin